# Simple method to save webpage in one file for offline viewing (print or mhtml only save the current page view)

Tags: google-chrome, archive, mhtml

The following URL has a number of click through images, and tabs. In this URL these images/tabs do not even change the URL. How can I archive this page and all images / tabs simply and in one convenient file for OFFLINE viewing?
[www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/property-70925028.html](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/property-70925028.html)

I have tried IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge. The closest is to save as a MHTML, but actually this only stores the current view in a single file (and not the other images, tabs which still need a connection). Many years ago IE Save As MHT used to work (I have some 13 year old .mht files) but this no longer works for offline viewing either.

I have also tried various browser extensions (Single File, Save Page WE), but none of them seem to create a file that works with internet disconnected, cached images deleted. And HTTrack and wget seem completely OTT and end up with multiple files and directories.

Any ideas?

- I am not worried about preserving formatting accuracy. Frankly it would be even better to just put all the images etc in a single PDF file if possible!? Then I know exactly what information I have forever!
- I would prefer it to be stored in a standard file format (PDF, MHTML etc) rather than a proprietary system that may or may not be around in 10 years

Running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: I'm the author of SingleFile and I confirm you can save this page and view it without needing to be connected to Internet.

Comment: Hi - sorry for slow response. I have just tried SingleFile, in Chrome, on the webpage above. I then disconnect the Ethernet, delete Chrome's cache, and load the file. Sure enough the page loads, but if I click on the images in the Slideshow they don't work. If I click on the "Floorplan" tab then that doesn't work either. I have tried loading it in IE and Firefox, neither of which work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your post. You have to save tabs separately unfortunately.

Comment: But, like all the browsers, it also doesn't save the Slide Show of pictures. I can save it as two files to get the 2nd tab, but saving a new file for each image in the slide show is a bit tedious, and I would have hoped not necessary. Is there another way?

Comment: You could open the "Print" page in a tab by forging for example the URL like this `https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-details/print.html?propertyId=70925028` and close the Print popup.

Comment: Thanks, you right in that the URL I gave does have a "Print" option that does do the required task perfectly. The problem is that many web pages do not have such a Print option...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no generic solution to this kind of issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Fireshot chrome extension pretty handy. Although not a proper solution to the problem, I have found the extension makes it quick and easy to capture all the elements of a page that you want.